# How to setup ServiceStack xUnit tests for a few services at once?

Tags: servicestack, xunit

how do you guys test a few services at once using ServiceStack and xUnit?
I have TestSetup that works all right and I inherit it by test classes like this:

```
public class TestSetup : IDisposable
{
protected ServiceStackHost appHost;

 public TestSetup()
    {
        appHost = new BasicAppHost().Init();

        var container = appHost.Container;
       //code
    }
}
```

then example test class constructor:

```
public exampleServiceTest() : base()
    {
        var container = appHost.Container;
       //RegisterAutoWired code
    }
```

And this works fine if I test one class at once, then another and so on. But if I want to run all tests, I get appHost instance already exists which is obvious. How should I solve this problem to be able to run all tests at once?

SOLUTION:
The solution is to create empty class that implements ICollectionFixture and decorate it with CollectionDefinition("Name"). Then you only have to decorate your test class with Collection("Name") and properly set test classes constructors (resolve services, create var container for that etc.). Pretty simple and clean solution on xUnit, everything works fine now. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Should also take some time and check docs https://docs.servicestack.net/testing

Answer (score 2):

You can't run multiple tests with AppHost's concurrently within the same AppDomain. The `appHost` instance your test uses needs to be disposed before the next integration test is run.

See [ServiceStack's Integration Tests example](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing#integration-testing) for how it uses NUnit's `[OneTimeTearDown]` to dispose of the AppHost after the test fixture is run:

```
public class CustomerRestExample
{
    const string BaseUri = "http://localhost:2000/";
    ServiceStackHost appHost;

    public CustomerRestExample()
    {
        //Start your AppHost on TestFixtureSetUp
        appHost = new AppHost() 
            .Init()
            .Start(BaseUri);
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void OneTimeTearDown() => appHost.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I don't use NUnit like I said, I use xUnit. I'll try OneTimeTearDown equvalent for xUnit which means  IClassFixture<T> to be implemented. This should work. Thanks for the suggestion.